# Visual Studio 2015 :is there any "post-debug" event?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015, envdte

I have an application that interacts with another one, suspending it while not used. If I end the debugging abruptly the suspended process will stay alive in the background and needs to be terminated.

I did some research and looks like [none](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605752/release-resources-when-stop-debugging) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334924/stop-development-server-when-i-stop-debugging) [the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033441/visual-studio-executing-clean-up-code-when-debugging-stops) [people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906422/can-i-really-not-clean-up-when-visual-studio-stops-debugging?lq=1) found a solution that is applicable to Visual Studio 2015, in particular the macro solution will not work since looks like a dropped feature since VS2010...

My current solution is to run the proper taskkill command as a post-build action and within the startup code of the program.

I'm looking for a more elegant way of killing it, so a "post-debug" event like the one portrayed by the macro below would be perfect:

```
Private Sub DebuggerEvents_OnEnterBreakMode(
   ByVal Reason As EnvDTE.dbgEventReason, 
   ByRef ExecutionAction As EnvDTE.dbgExecutionAction) Handles DebuggerEvents.OnEnterBreakMode
    If (Reason = dbgEventReason.dbgEventReasonStopDebugging) Then
        KillLeftoverProgram()
    End If
End Sub
```

So is there any way to execute a cleanup shell command after using the stop button?